# How do i make answers to a trivia quiz be placed randomly in button slots

Tags: javascript, html, dom, random

So i'm using a trivia game api to request trivia questions for a webapp i'm programming. I've figured out how to randomize it but i can't figure out how to not make it repeat options.

```
function useApiData(data){
  let answers= [data.results[0].correct_answer, data.results[0].incorrect_answers[0], data.results[0].incorrect_answers[1], data.results[0].incorrect_answers[2]]

  document.querySelector("#category").innerHTML = `Category: ${data.results[0].category}`
  document.querySelector("#difficulty").innerHTML = `Difficulty: ${data.results[0].difficulty}`
  document.querySelector("#question").innerHTML = `Question: ${data.results[0].question}`
  document.querySelector("#answer1").innerHTML = `${answers[Math.floor(Math.random()*answers.length)]}`
  document.querySelector("#answer2").innerHTML = `${answers[Math.floor(Math.random()*answers.length)]}`
  document.querySelector("#answer3").innerHTML = `${answers[Math.floor(Math.random()*answers.length)]}`
  document.querySelector("#answer4").innerHTML = `${answers[Math.floor(Math.random()*answers.length)]}`
}
```

Comment: pull out each answer one at a time from the array - randomly select one element, store it and make a new list that has everything but that element, then repeat until only one answer is left

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys. I'll try one them out tomorrow. if anyone is curious as to how its looking right now. Here

https://7-2-trivia-api.glitch.me

Comment: Please keep in mind, if one of the answers works for you, please mark them as the answer to help other peeps in the community to find their solution easier if they facing the same issue. You can do this by using grey marks (tick) beside answers (you can only choose one), for more information please read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Comment: Did you come up with a conclusion?

Answer (score 1):

So to make it work as you expected you should **pop each selected item in the array out, then make a new choice between existing ones**.

It should be something like this:

```js
function randomItemWithNoRepetition(array) {
  let copy = Array.from(array); // Create a copy of input array
  return function() {
    if (copy.length < 1) { copy = Array.from(array); } // This line exist to create copy and make a new array from actual array whenever all possible options are selected once
    const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * copy.length); // Select an index randomly
    const item = copy[index]; // Get the index value
    copy.splice(index, 1); // Remove selected element from copied array
    return item; // Return selected element
  };
}

const chooseFromArray = randomItemWithNoRepetition(['Foo', 'Bar', 'FU', 'FooBar' ]); // The input of this function should be the array of your answers. I just add dummy data as an input of function for more illustration.

document.querySelector("#answer1").innerHTML = `${chooseFromArray()}`; // "Bar"
document.querySelector("#answer2").innerHTML = `${chooseFromArray()}`; // "Foo"
document.querySelector("#answer3").innerHTML = `${chooseFromArray()}`; // "FU"
document.querySelector("#answer4").innerHTML = `${chooseFromArray()}`; // "FooBar"
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript arrays have a method called [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)() which sorts all the answers given a specified function, a negative number sends the element back in the array and a positive number sends it forward, so given that you can make a quick function to sort an array randomly like so:

```
function sortArrayRandomly(array) {
  return array.concat().sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random());
}
```

this function will sort your array in a random order, you can then use it in your code like so:

```
function useApiData(data){
  let answers = sortArrayRandomly([data.results[0].correct_answer, data.results[0].incorrect_answers[0], data.results[0].incorrect_answers[1], data.results[0].incorrect_answers[2]]);

  document.querySelector("#category").innerHTML = `Category: ${data.results[0].category}`
  document.querySelector("#difficulty").innerHTML = `Difficulty: ${data.results[0].difficulty}`
  document.querySelector("#question").innerHTML = `Question: ${data.results[0].question}`
  document.querySelector("#answer1").innerHTML = `${answers[0]}`
  document.querySelector("#answer2").innerHTML = `${answers[1]}`
  document.querySelector("#answer3").innerHTML = `${answers[2]}`
  document.querySelector("#answer4").innerHTML = `${answers[3]}`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A good way to randomize an array is called the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://www.programming-algorithms.net/article/43676/Fisher-Yates-shuffle) algorithm.
You can use it as follows.

(Run the snippet multiple times to see that the answers are randomly ordered.)

```js
// Defines the answers and the corresponding HTML elements
let answers = ["JavaScript", "42", "Maybe", "Leroy Jenkins"];
const answerElements = [
  document.getElementById("answer1"),
  document.getElementById("answer2"),
  document.getElementById("answer3"),
  document.getElementById("answer4")
];

// Shuffles the answers
randomize(answers);

// Loops through the randomized answers
for(let i = 0; i < answers.length; i++){

  // Checks to be sure the property we're assigning to exists
  if(answerElements[i] && answerElements[i].textContent){
    
    // Assigns the string to the element's textContent property
    answerElements[i].textContent = answers[i];
  }
}

// Implements a Fisher-Yates shuffle
function randomize(array){
  for(let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--){
    const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
    const tmp = array[index];
    array[index] = array[i];
    array[i] = tmp;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="answer1">1</div>
<div id="answer2">2</div>
<div id="answer3">3</div>
<div id="answer4">4</div>
```